# How to extract child element while ignoring parent?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to webscrape from an html table to Excel and struggling with a specific website's design.

From what I understand, most tables are organized with tags like: ( table -> tr -> td ) as in, table then row then cell.

I can deal with that, but the 'main-table' I'm trying to extract from has tables and rows contained within a cell, like ('main table -> row -> cell -> sub-table ->sub-row -> sub-cell). I can't get a clean Excel sheet

Here's what the html looks like:

detailed html
[image]

overview html
[image]

I need to extract only the `NCI` and `$392,764`.
So far, I'm extracting duplicates of these values using the `.innertext` command.

I want to grab only the `lastchild` element from each parent cell.

```vb
Sub processhtmlpage(htmlpage As mshtml.HTMLDocument)
    
    Dim htmlTable As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim htmlTables As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim htmlrows As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim htmlcell As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim rownum As Long, colnum As Integer
    
    Set htmlTables = htmlpage.getElementsByTagName("table")
    Set HTMLInnerTables = htmlpage.getElementsByTagName("table")
    Set HTMLInnerRows = htmlpage.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    
        For Each htmlTable In htmlTables
            Worksheets.Add
            Range("a1").Value = htmlTable.className
            Range("b1").Value = Now
            rownum = 2
                For Each HTMLRow In htmlTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                colnum = 1
                    For Each htmlcell In HTMLRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                        Cells(rownum, colnum) = htmlcell.innerText
                        colnum = colnum + 1
                    Next htmlcell
                    rownum = rownum + 1
                Next HTMLRow
        Next htmlTable
    End Sub
```

I made some attempts to circumvent this by using if...then commands. In case it is helpful, here's what I ended up with:

```vb
Sub processhtmlpage(htmlpage As mshtml.HTMLDocument)
    
    Dim htmlTable As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim htmlTables As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim htmlrows As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim htmlcell As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim rownum As Long, colnum As Integer
    Dim HTMLInnerTables As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLInnerTable As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLInnerRow As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLInnerows As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim innerhtmlcell As mshtml.IHTMLElement
    
    Set htmlTables = htmlpage.getElementsByTagName("table")
    Set HTMLInnerTables = htmlpage.getElementsByTagName("table")
    Set HTMLInnerRows = htmlpage.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    
    For Each htmlTable In htmlTables
        If htmlTable.getAttribute("id") <> "main-table" Then
            GoTo line4
        End If
    
        Worksheets.Add
        Range("a1").Value = htmlTable.className
        Range("b1").Value = Now
        rownum = 2
                   
        For Each HTMLRow In htmlTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            If HTMLRow.getAttribute("bgcolor") = "#ffffff" Or HTMLRow.getAttribute("class") = "lop" Then
                GoTo line6
            End If
            colnum = 1
                
            For Each htmlcell In HTMLRow.getElementsByTagName("td") [line 6]
                If htmlcell.getAttribute("nowrap") = "nowrap" Then
                    GoTo line1
                Else
                    If htmlcell.getAttribute("colspan") = 2 Then
                        Cells(rownum, colnum) = htmlcell.innerText
                        rownum = rownum + 1
                        Call stupidcell
                    Else
                    End If
                    For Each HTMLInnerTable In htmlcell.getElementsByTagName("table")
                        
                        If HTMLInnerTable.getAttribute("id") <> "main-table" Then
                            GoTo line1
                        End If
                    Next HTMLInnerTable
                    For Each HTMLInnerRow In htmlcell.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                        If HTMLInnerRow.getAttribute("bgcolor") = "#ffffff" Then
                            GoTo line1
                        End If
                    Next HTMLInnerRow [line5]
                Next HTMLInnerTable
                Cells(rownum, colnum) = htmlcell.innerText [line2]
                colnum = colnum + 1
            Next htmlcell [line1]
            rownum = rownum + 1
        Next HTMLRow [line3]
    Next htmlTable [line4]
End Sub
```

Comment: A HTML screenshot including the higher-level nesting would be useful - for example showing where the "top level" table (id="MainTable") is defined.  Your starting point should be `Set tbl = htmlpage.getElementById("main-table")` and then drill down from there.  Your code is pretty generic but the actual structure is predictable/specific, so you could use a much simpler approach.

Comment: hi thanks.  I've added a second html image "overview html" to give you some context.  Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Please use the snippet tool available via [edit] to insert HTML. Don't use images. The ability to copy and paste facilitates better quality answers as we can test with your HTML. Include an URL where possible as well.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but would advise against using GoTo. It's a relic from the days of BASIC and makes your code harder to read and maintain. Save it for when absolutely necessary, such as error handling (because VBA has no concept of Try/Catch)

Answer (score 1):

This is **not an answer** and so will probably get flagged, but this is the only way to leave a comment including graphics, so maybe the S.O. Gods will let it slide (otherwise, I'll just delete!)

---

When I have a complicated set of nested `For`'s/`If`'s, I'll copy it to a text editor (preferably Notepad++) and remove all the code except for the nested parts, and organize it so I can see where my problem is.

The first procedure is nested properly:
[image: img]

The second procedure has a problem, noted in Red:
[image: img]

You're closing the `For` for `HTMLInnerTable` twice.

Comment: Nice strategy ++

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very basic start at extracting the text from the table - you just need to target the cells of interest and perform a little cleanup on the text.

Definitely not a "web standards" approach, but sometimes a rough and ready method is easier to manage, and there's little point getting too elaborate when a small change in the page layout can ruin the whole thing.

```
Sub NIHTable()

    Dim htmlpage, tbl, rw, cl, rownum, cellNum

    'populate htmlpage

    Set tbl = htmlpage.document.getElementById("main-table")
    rownum = 0
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        rownum = rownum + 1
        Debug.Print "------ Row# " & rownum
        cellNum = 0
        For Each cl In rw.Cells
            cellNum = cellNum + 1
            Debug.Print , cellNum, Trim(Replace(cl.innerText, vbCrLf, ";"))
        Next cl
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Sample row output:

```
------ Row# 9
               1            
               2            1 R43 CA23616401
               3            
               4            DEVELOPMENT OF TARGETED, SAFE AND EFFECTIVE DRUGS AGAINST PANCREATIC DUCTAL ADENOCARCINOMA (PDAC) BY LEVERAGING A NOVEL, COMPREHENSIVE, COMPUTATIONAL DRUG DISCOVERY APPROACH
               5            HEUER, TIM S.
               6            TWOXAR, INC.
               7            2018
               8            NCI
               9            ,NCI ,,$225,030
               10
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution I was hoping for, thanks so much!  Works quite well with excel.  Need to work on understanding your trim(replace(........) portion but will figure that out

Comment: That's an artifact of the weird nesting/formatting in the source - all that does is remove line breaks and trim off any extra spaces: really needs a more robust approach though.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual HTML to use this is not tested. I especially can't see what other elements may match the following CSS selector pattern.

The items you want have `table` tagged parents. More specifically, they are in a child `td` element with class `lop` that has an attribute `align`, that is inside a `tr` element with class `lop`. Using CSS descendant combinator syntax that looks like:

```
table tr.lop [align]td.lop
```

You could gather elements matching this pattern with `querySelectorAll` method of `HTMLDocument` as follows:

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long
Set nodeList = htmlpage.querySelectorAll("table tr.lop [align]td.lop
")
For i = 0 To nodeList.Length-1
    Debug.Print Trim$(nodeList.item(i).innerText)
Next
```

---

If duplicated values are still a problem consider loading retrieved values into a dictionary and emptying that at the end

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long, dict As Object
Set nodeList = htmlpage.querySelectorAll("table tr.lop [align]td.lop")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    dict(Trim$(nodeList.item(i).innerText)) = vbNullString
Next
Dim arr()
arr = dict.keys '<== retrieve unique values
```

Comment: Did you try this please?